# Rendering YUV video on Android, textures aren't being uploaded to texture units

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I ported working code from C++ to Java. In C++ I used the same shaders as here and the same code, and I was able to use 3 texture units of the GPU to load the `Y`, `U` and `V` components and then use `texture()` to join these textures into an RGBA buffer to be rendered.

The problem is that in Android I see a green screen, which is the RGBA color that is generated by the shader when empty `Y`,`U` and `V` texture units are given. So the textures are not being uploaded. I turned off all the pixel buffer things and trid to simply `glTexImage2D` with a simple buffer and also didn't see any change.

```
 public boolean renderYUV(DecodedFrame decodedFrame) throws Exception {
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexInLocation);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureInLocation);

        if (!initiatedTextures)
        {
            glGenTextures(TEXTURE_NUMBER, textureId);

            for (int i = 0; i < TEXTURE_NUMBER; i++)
            {
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId.get(i));
                glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pixelBufferObjects.get(i));
                glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, decodedFrame.textureSize[i], null, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
                glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                            0,
                            GL_RED,
                            decodedFrame.width[i],
                            decodedFrame.height[i],
                            0,
                            GL_RED,
                            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                            null); //decodedFrame->buffer[i]);
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
                glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            }
            initiatedTextures = true;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < TEXTURE_NUMBER; j++)
        {
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + j);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId.get(j));
            glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pixelBufferObjects.get(j));

            if (true)//todo: change to verify if buffer has contents
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= decodedFrame.height[j] - 1; i++)
                {
                    int offset = i * decodedFrame.linesize[j];
                    glBufferSubData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, offset, decodedFrame.width[j], decodedFrame.buffer[j]);
                }
                glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        decodedFrame.width[j],
                        decodedFrame.height[j],
                        GL_RED,
                        GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                        null);
            }
            glUniform1i(textureLocation[j], j);
        }
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        return true;
    }
```

Here are the shaders:

Vertex:

```
#version 320 es
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec2 TexCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);
}
```

Fragment:

```
#version 320 es

#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump int;
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform sampler2D tex_y;
uniform sampler2D tex_u;
uniform sampler2D tex_v;

in vec2 TexCoord;
out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    vec3 yuv;
    vec4 rgba;
    yuv.r = texture(tex_y, TexCoord).r - 0.0625;
    yuv.g = texture(tex_u, TexCoord).r - 0.5;
    yuv.b = texture(tex_v, TexCoord).r - 0.5;

    rgba.r = yuv.r + 1.402 * yuv.b;
    rgba.g = yuv.r - 0.34413 * yuv.g - 0.71414 * yuv.b;
    rgba.b = yuv.r + 1.772 * yuv.g;
    FragColor = rgba;
}
```

I verified that `tex_y`, `tex_u`, and `tex_v` are being loaded (glGetUniformLocation works) and the shaders compile without any problems. I also exchange `FragColor = rgba` by `FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f)` and say a red image, confirming that the shader is working, the only problem being the textures being empty. So I'm pretty sure the problem is related to filling the textures. As you can see, `glUniform1i(textureLocation[j], j);` activates the `Sampler2D` for each uniform variable, so that's also not the problem.

Can someone spot something easy that I'm missing in Java that is different from C++?

Just to add a little bit more of information, here's my vertex and texture coordinates:

```
static float vertex[] = {
        -1.0f,  -1.0f, 0.0f, // top left
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
        1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f    // top right
}; 
static float fragment[] = {
        0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f
};

//create vertexBuffer and fragmentBuffer from the arrays here

GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(vertexInLocation, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 3*4, vertexBuffer);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexInLocation);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureInLocation, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 2*4, fragmentBuffer);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureInLocation);
```